# How to create a chart for tracking Product stock over some period of time using Ubercart?

Tags: 6, ubercart, charts

Does anybody know about a good solution for tracking Product stock in a certain timespan?

It is nice to see the stock numbers of products, but I find quite handy to see product performance **over time**.

**My Questions**: Is there any module for this? Or is it more appropriate to create such Product stock tracking using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)?

*Edit*: Maybe it's possible to record some "Product stock"-field into some database?

Comment: Can you not just create a view based on sales?

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? I need to see how stock levels changed daily. As for graph - as I commented on @harshal answer - I am not aware that stock historical values are saved into database. It contains only up to date values for each product.

Comment: you can use answer from this question to log stock logs. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29398/get-historical-stock-level-in-ubercart. And then use those data for your chart or graph tool

Comment: Looks that this is the way to go. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [views charts](https://drupal.org/project/views_charts) for creating graph

> About the Project
>
> Provides a "charts" style output for Views module so you can render
>   result-set not just as text (list, tabular) but as pie-chart,
>   bar-chart, scatter-plot etc.
>
> DC DrupalCon '09 Presentation
>
> http://vimeo.com/5306364
>
> Dependencies
>
> Views Charts and Graphs Suggested modules
>
> For Drupal 6 you will need the Views GroupBy: if you want to chart
>   anything actually useful. Views 3 for Drupal 7 has grouping built in.
>   Documentation
>
> Views Charts has basic usage instructions available as Advanced Help
>   pages. Please install and enable it to see the available help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, well I was thinking about charts but there is one problem - that the historical stock values are not saved into database. There are only actual, up to date values as far as I know. So there are no values I can build a graph from, unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

From My Professional experience you can use Highcharts in drupal. Usually highcharts also have its own significances with views but I will suggest you guys to use highcharts libraries with visualization module. You have much flexibility to use CHARTS IN VIEW As per required + Filters and all other stuff also works quite Smoothly with highcharts. You also have lot of other options also to use with visulization API.

It also allows you to create custom charts serving the data from database or wherever you want.

Important Links :
Visualisation : https://www.drupal.org/project/visualization

References :
Screencast : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot2cFQVgzfA